# ObjectOutputStream does not write objects when taking BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, file-io, objectoutputstream

I've done my research but it seems I can't find enough documentation on the subject.

When trying out some code on [Object streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html), I came to notice that putting a **BufferedOutputStream** inside an **ObjectOutputStream** causes the file to be *ill-written*. Just to makes things clearer here's the code I've used:

```
public class Objectstream implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int x;

public Objectstream(){}
public Objectstream(int x){
    this.x = x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try(
            //ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/homes/f17oudbi/Bureau/o.txt")));//1
            ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("o.txt"));//2
            ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("o.txt"));
            
            ){
        
        Objectstream obj = new Objectstream(7);

        objOutStream.writeObject(obj);
        objOutStream.flush();

        System.out.println(((Objectstream)objInputStream.readObject()).x);

        
    }catch(EOFException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

If I decomment the first line and comment the second, the written Objectstream just writes `\AC\ED\00\00` in the file (and that's independant of how I change it); But if I keep the code as is, it writes something with the reference on the object and does the job well.

Does anyone have an explanation why is this the case?

**Edit:**

I get the following exception `java.io.EOFException` pointing to the line where the `ObjectOutputStream` method is created.

Comment: Well you're never closing the `ObjectOutputStream`, which could cause problems, I suspect.

Comment: I am using a try-with-resources, so I assume that's taken care of. (edit) Plus I am not using it anyways in either of the cases, so that must not be the probem.

Comment: Ah, had missed that. Yes, that should close it fine. (It would make everything easier to read if you'd reformat the code... including the imports would also make it easier to reproduce)

Comment: Now I suspect the `ObjectOutputStream` implements its own buffers, but why that choice and how precisely is still escaping me..

Comment: The fact that you're trying to read from a file and write to it at the same time is quite possibly a problem though. Do you observe the same behaviour if you remove the input part? (I get 33 bytes with the uncommented code.)

Comment: Interesting, I suspected that and removed it but nothing changed. Seems as though only the presence or absence of the `BufferedOutputStream` causes the behavior to change.

Comment: I suspect you've got a diagnostic error then - because it works fine for me, and the reading completely explains the behaviour you were seeing - see my answer. You should show the exception that's being thrown too - I assume you *are* seeing an exception?

Comment: Yes, just edited my post accordingly. It's an EOFException actually.

Comment: You claim that it points to the line where readObject is called - that's not what I'm seeing. I'm seeing it in the ObjectInputStream constructor. Please update the question again with the actual stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, edited, my bad :/ !

Comment: Including the stack trace would still be clearer, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to create the `ObjectInputStream` on the same file that you're writing to - you never even get into the body of your try-with-resources block.

Here's what happens:

- Create the `FileOutputStream`: file is empty
- Wrap it in `BufferedOutputStream`: file stays empty
- Wrap it in `ObjectOutputStream`: the OOS writes data to the BufferedOutputStream, but it's buffered
- Create a `FileInputStream`
- Create an `ObjectInputStream` - that tries to read from the input stream, finds it's empty, and throws an exception
- The input stream is closed
- The output stream is closed, which flushes the buffers and *then* you get the four bytes

Basically, I'd strongly advise you not to try to read from the same stream you're writing to - I doubt that this is the only problem it will cause.

Comment: Ok this must be it, actually when trying to read without writing I was still reading the ill-written file, once I totally separated the writing and reading, it worked just fine.